# ESXi VM details

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, esxi

I have an ESXi which has 10 vm's running on it.

I need a way to get all the details of each VM, like CPU,memory and storage details.

```
esxcli vm process list
```

it lists only VM's not their details.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the command you are currently using seems to be limited.

One solution would be to download the [VMWare PowerCLI PowerShell module](https://developer.vmware.com/powercli) in order to control your ESXi host remotely from a shell. It offers a wide list of cmdlets in order to automate many processes and I am sure that it could help you out in this case.

I also, found an [automated script](https://www.enterprisedaddy.com/2016/09/powercli-find-virtual-machines-details/) from this tool that looks familiar to your needs.